# JBoss6.1 and Axis2 Compatibility issues

Tags: apache-axis, jboss6.x

I am using Eclipse Helios and added Axis2 required libraries for a Web Application which is running on JBoss6.1, when I start the server I see following error log. Please help in getting this resolved.

```
WARN  [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.w3c.dom.UserDataHandler: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
```

---

### --Removed Some portion of Log --here

```
11:06:39,781 WARN  [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.w3c.dom.DOMConfiguration: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at     
11:06:39,828 WARN  [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]

11:06:39,891 WARN  [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:280) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]


11:06:39,938 WARN  [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.w3c.dom.UserDataHandler: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]

11:06:40,031 WARN  [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.w3c.dom.UserDataHandler: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:280) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1172) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:610) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl$2.run(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:198) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl$2.run(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:194) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getMethods(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:193) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.ClassInfoImpl.getDeclaredMethods(ClassInfoImpl.java:416) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ClassHierarchyResourceVisitor.handleClass(ClassHierarchyResourceVisitor.java:80) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.doVisit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:108) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:86) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.AnnotationsScanningPlugin.visit(AnnotationsScanningPlugin.java:89) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.ScanningPluginWrapper.visit(ScanningPluginWrapper.java:112) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.visitor.FederatedResourceVisitor.visit(FederatedResourceVisitor.java:101) [jboss-classloading.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:264) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:409) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:411) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:397) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:102) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.classloader.VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.visit(VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:181) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.DeploymentUnitScanner.scan(DeploymentUnitScanner.java:111) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.UrlScanner.scan(UrlScanner.java:96) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.deployers.ScanningDeployer.deploy(ScanningDeployer.java:95) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_27]

11:06:42,407 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/cmrDataProjNew1
```

Comment: Interestingly, I removed the xmlbeans.(version).jar file and now I don't see these errors, but the problem is my application required XMLBeans, Any suggestions on how to include XMLBeans in the project workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleaner way is to first add all the desired Aixs2 jars in the project and then deploy the project in JBoss once you do that you will run into "TypeInfo or the above mentioned class DataHandler" class issue with classloader. The clurpit is XMLBeans.(someversion).jar contains conflicting classes in package "org/w3c/dom/" which are already there in JBoss common/lib, if you remove these classes from XMLBeans.(someversion).jar the issues will get resolved.